# Android E/cutils-trace(1263): Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

Tags: android, gridview

I've been searching for the solution to this problem for days and had no lucky.

Every time I click on a gridview, this error comes out in the log cat (the app does not crashes, just shows the error):

E/cutils-trace(1263): Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

I'm following this tutorial:
http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/

Thank you in advance!
José.

Comment: Are u getting expected result or it just don’t do anything after that error?

Comment: @Braj I'm getting the result that I expect...

Comment: I realized that the error is happening on all the Apps I have, on all the emulators I create... is it my eclipse?

Comment: Not sure, may b some system error/warning. You can ignore I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I had an error like this one, and I just added a SD card to my emulator. If it doesn't work with a SD card added, make a new device with a SD card and try it like that.